# Значения аргументов функции по умолчанию

Tags: c++

```
void foo(int a = 10, double b = 1.023)
```

Где хранятся значения данных параметров?

Comment: В памяти компилятора во время компиляции...

Comment: Вопрос "где"  здесь очень не корректен - потому как на него можно ответить просто "в памяти", а вот когда выделяется память для этих чисел и используется это уже совсем другой вопрос, который обычно преставляет больший интерес - в вашем случае это может происходить во время компиляции.

Comment: Там же, где хранится мягкий знак в слове "храняться".

Comment: Эти значения параметров по умолчанию хранятся там же, где и обычные числовые литералы. А вот где - точно не сформулирую.

Comment: При компиляции вызов `f(5)` просто заменяется на `f(5, 1.023)` для вашего случая

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Они нигде не хранятся. Вызов функции с аргументами по-умолчанию эквивалентен вызову функции с подстановкой указанных аргументов в месте вызова. Соответственно

1. аргументы по-умолчанию до вызова функции вообще не существуют;
2. при вызове функции для них будет использоваться то же самое хранилище объектов с автоматическим временем хранения, что и при ручном указании этих аргументов;

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос "где" здесь очень не корректен - потому как на него можно ответить просто "в памяти", а вот когда выделяется память для этих чисел и используется это уже совсем другой вопрос, который обычно преставляет больший интерес - в вашем случае это может происходить во время компиляции.

Comment: *"Вопрос "где" здесь очень не корректен - потому как на него можно ответить просто "в памяти""* По такой логике можно сказать, что вопросы вроде "где хранится объект, созданный `new`" тоже "некорректны", потому что тоже можно ответить "в памяти".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat на этот вопрос можно ответить "в динамической памяти" а на вопрос просто "где" невозможно конкретно сказать "когда", поэтому он и не корректен